# Eclipse-RCP: View pulldown-menu

Tags: view, menu, eclipse-rcp

I would like to add `Command`'s to a View's pulldown-menu (the triangle-shaped button in the upper right corner that the "Problems"-View in Eclipse also has).
Can anyone point me in the right direction how to do this declaratively in plugin.xml?

I found a tutorial that used a viewContribution (extension point `org.eclipse.ui.viewActions`), but unfortunately using this extension point i can only add `Action`'s to this menu.

The functionality i wish is actually quite similar to the Problems-View (Showing Compiler-Errors and -Warnings in Eclipse):

I want to filter records within my View according to an Entry chosen in the pulldown-menu of the View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an example configuration you can use the implementation of the Problem View itself. It uses the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to contribute that menuItem through a dynamic contributor. You can check the details in the plugin.xml of the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin. Look for the usage of the class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.FiltersContribution`. In its `"getContributionItems()"` method it returns menu contributions dynamically each time the menu is to appear. Of course, doing it this way is not exactly declarative. For that try reading the guide at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_menus.htm (you should use your command instead of the global ones, of course)

Hope it helps!